# Textboxes not working on Firefox only

Tags: wordpress, firefox, textbox, contact-form

here's the site with the problem. shop.theclickshop.net

I used wordpress as the backend with contact form 7 plugin for the text box forms in the left pop up.

For some strange reason, I can't click on the textboxes on firefox but works perfectly fine on every other browser.

Is there something I should do to make it work on firefox as well?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I just found the problem. It was a script that disabled text selection. Once I removed it it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran into problems with the firefox 10 upgrade not being supported by the infragistics code we use at work. It is so new that if you are using 10 that could be your problem.  We found that downgrading to firefox 9 was best until we could test and support the new firefox release.